# Logical OR in combination with lodash get() gives weird results

Tags: javascript

OK, so I can't wrap my head around this...

I need to find a `bankScheme` and there is some code before this snippet that might find it so I have set it to `ABC` to illustrate that the value was found.
If it still wasn't found I wanted to try to find it from some other data, object `j` in the snippet below but as object `j` might not contain `PaymentMeans` I used the lodash `_.get()` to fetch the value (in the real object the path is much "deeper").

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let j = { PaymentMeans: '12' };
let bankScheme = 'ABC';
// Let's try the OR operand with a lodash function:
bankScheme = bankScheme || _.get(j, 'PaymentMeans') === '58' ? '58Found' : '58NotFound';

console.log(_.get(j, 'PaymentMeans'), bankScheme);
// It now logs '12 58Found' which is very weird as it should log 'ABC' in any case, and even if it didn't find 'ABC' it should log '58NotFound'...
// If however bankScheme = null then the _.get() works as expected
```

The weird thing here is, firstly, that the logical OR (`||`) is not doing what I would expect it to, and that is to leave the value as `ABC` as it is not "*falsy*" to begin with.

Secondly, if we accept that the OR is not working, the return should be `58NotFound` but now it is `58Found`...

What am I missing?

Writing it as this works as expceted though:

```
bankScheme = bankScheme ? bankScheme : _.get(j, 'PaymentMeans') === '58' ? '58Found' : '58NotFound';
```

Code: https://repl.it/join/hjqoaatb-anderswa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget about the operator priority.

This

```
bankScheme = bankScheme || _.get(j, 'PaymentMeans') === '58' ? '58Found' : '58NotFound';
```

is equivalent to this:

```
bankScheme = (bankScheme || _.get(j, 'PaymentMeans') === '58') ? '58Found' : '58NotFound';
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense (and I wasn't aware of "operator priority")... (bankScheme || _.get(j, 'PaymentMeans') === '58') = 'ABC' then and as 'ABC' is a "truthy" value it picks '58Found'... Jeez...

Answer (score 1):

You need to group correctly.

```js
bankScheme = bankScheme || (_.get(j, 'PaymentMeans') === '58' ? '58Found' : '58NotFound');
```

You can find a good read about operator priorities [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Comment: Ah, yes, that works too but I'll mark @Zoli's answer as the correct one because of the explanation...